# SharePoint Online Lookup Dropdown Autocomplete/Combobox

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, lookup-column, jquery-ui

I have a list in Sharepoint Online, which has a lookup to an other list. No matter what, on the form it will always render as a dropdown value. When this list of values becomes huge, it's hard to find the correct item in the dropdown.

Therefore I want to implement something like this: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

This will allow to type in the lookup field and find the correct item easily. Is this possible and how can I implement this?

Kind regards,

Christian

Comment: jQuery/Javascript would be the way to do it, check this forum post which discuss something very similar to what you are looking for: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104615/autocomplete-lookup-finding-the-best-approach

Comment: I tried the SPServices Autocomplete function, but this is not what i'm looking for, because this function uses a Single Line of Text field as input. I need to render the lookup dropdown value in a different way...

Comment: Simply query for the items you want to be in the autocomplete/combobox using REST or JSOM, then follow the steps you'd normally take to create the dropdown.

Comment: Maybe also good to know is that i already use $().SPServices.SPLookupAddNew to my lookup dropdown field, which adds the option for creating new lookup values in the sourcelist.